# custom route via POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 4.0

In routes.rb I have code

```
get "test/index"
```

It works fine. But when I add custom route like:

```
post "test/some_controller_action"
```

And then send file via curl

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d @result.json http://localhost:3000/test/some_controller_action
```

I get the error

```
Started POST "/test/some_controller_action" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-15 14:28:11 +0700
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/test/some_controller_action"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
```

rake routes:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
test_index GET  /test/index(.:format)      test#index
test_some_controller_action POST /test/some_controller_action(.:format) test#some_controller_action
```

What is wrong with that route?

Comment: Did you actually create the controller.

Comment: you have a typo `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/turizm/create_info"):` see `turizm` could this be the error?

Comment: @juanpastas, edited post.
@MichaelSzyndel, I created it with ```rails g controller test index``` and then I manually added action ```some_controller_action``` and route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your routes and see your routes by running rake routes

```
 match '/test/some_controller_action' => 'test#some_controller_action', :via => :post, :as => :some_controller_action
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this format over others because this offers better maintainability. Note, the `:on => :collection` part is important, whichever way you prefer.

```
resources :test do
  post :some_controller_action, :on => :collection
end
```

HTH

Comment: I don't understand. What is the ```:collection``` in my case?